# Overriding IndexIgnore in .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have `IndexIgnore *` in a directory for which I don't want to allow directory listing.

Now, in a **sub-directory**, I want to `override` the `IndexIgnore` directive defined in parent directory and **allow** directory listing.

The documentation for [IndexIgnore](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore) says

```
The IndexIgnore directive adds to the list of files to hide when listing a directory.
```

How do I allow directory listing for this sub-directory?

Answer (score 5):

You may reset the `IndexIgnore list`by using the option

```
IndexIgnoreReset ON
```

[See the documentation here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignorereset)

Comment: Should be the accepted answer because it does what was asked for.

Comment: Note that `IndexIgnoreReset` is an Apache 2.4 directive. Apache 2.2 (as stated in the question and was asked 2 years before Apache 2.4 was released) does not support this. However, since the OP is wanting to completely disable (and enable) directory listings then `Options -Indexes` would be the preferred option (as stated in the other answer).

Answer (score 4):

Try `Options -Indexes` instead.  If this `.htaccess` file applies to the sub-directory with `Indexes`, try specifying `+Indexes`.

Best practices often entail specifying these settings within httpd.conf  instead if you're the system administrator. Also, it's more risky from a security perspective even to enable .htaccess files in the first place. If the Web server or application user were compromised, this would be one of the first places that could be written to without complete compromise.

If specified in the Apache configuration file instead, you would often specify `Options` within a `Directory` section.

[Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)

Answer (score 2):

FYI, what you are looking for does not seems to be possible: [Re: [users@httpd] IndexIgnore](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/200909.mbox/%3C553da56d0909291506t4c295ccxd84fd452cb20beb4@mail.gmail.com%3E)

(I found this and your question looking for a solution to the same problem.)

Comment: Pretty sure this answer is outdated

Answer (score 0):

In the `.htaccess` of the sub-directory to allow:

```
IndexIgnoreReset ON
Options All +Indexes
```

I also added:

```
IndexIgnore ..
```

...to prevent browsing to the parent directory.